# Find Cookie files and edit them with notepad / other editor

Tags: cookies

Hi I'm having problems finding the cookie files for chrome and explorer.

I can view them using the crhome debug tool but what I want to do is to get directly to the files location and edit them.

Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It stores the data here:

C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\

However, it is in SQLite database format.

You will have to use [SQLite Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) to open or another like program

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
Updated link for the latest SQLite browser : https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/